# Update header after initializing ApolloProvider

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I use uploadLink in order to set the headers used for making requests to my Apollo server (see code below). However, after I login I would like to reset the header because the 'organizationid' which is included as well in the header, is not yet available in local storage during initialization of Apollo Provider. I only get the 'organizationid' from the Apollo server from a query after being logged in.

```
const {othertoken} = queryString.parse(window.location.search)

const header = {
    Authorization: ' Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accounts:accessToken'),
    othertoken,
    organizationid: localStorage.getItem('organizationId')
}

const uri = CONFIG.graphQLServerTest

const uploadLink = createUploadLink({uri, headers: header})
const cache = new InMemoryCache()

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    resolvers: merge(dashboardStore.resolvers, collectionStore.resolvers, templateStore.resolvers, documentStore.resolvers) as any,
    link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, uploadLink])
})


cache.writeData({data: collectionStore.defaults})
cache.writeData({data: dashboardStore.defaults})
cache.writeData({data: documentStore.defaults})
cache.writeData({data: templateStore.defaults})

const accountsGraphQL = new GraphQLClient({graphQLClient: apolloClient})
const accountsClient = new AccountsClient({}, accountsGraphQL)
const accountsPassword = new AccountsClientPassword(accountsClient)

export {accountsClient, accountsGraphQL, accountsPassword, apolloClient}
```

I need the 'organizationid' included in each of the queries I send to the server in all of the queries after I have saved it in local storage. For this purpose I need to re-initialize the header after I save 'organizationid' in local storage. Is there a way to do this?

I would like to avoid including 'organizationid' as query parameter to all of my queries.

Comment: just like token after login? check auth in apollo docs

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use authLink but it seems to interfere with the library for authentication that I use - meaning the context I set using authLink doesn't arrive on the server.

Comment: using links is the right method to include headers with dynamic data - debbug it ... prepare working [example] on codesandbox ... creating next/another workaround is not the right way ... it should work https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3302

Comment: Thanks. I was now able to solve it using setContext! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by using an authLink created with setContext:

```
const authLink = setContext((_, {headers}) => {
    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            organizationid: localStorage.getItem('organizationId')
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: you forgot to include existing headers ( `...headers,`) - this way, you're replacing them with only one

Comment: I don't understand why, but for some reason in my case it seems that the header is not overwritten (I guess because my auth library --> accounts-js takes care of it). thanks!

Comment: I changed it anyway now although it seems not to have an impact in my case